# Call api with axios since my component and my store

Tags: axios, components, vuejs3, store

I'm new to Vue 3 (cli) and I'm not at all comfortable with front-end technology, so I'm having a hard time understanding the information I'm reading.

I succeeded in creating a registration/login interface with an api and JWT. The user information needs to be persisted everywhere in the project I'm doing to train myself, so I configured axios in my store.

```
store/index.js

import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:7000'
});

let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
if(null === user) {
  user = {uuid: '', token: ''};
} else {
  try {
    user = JSON.parse(user);
    api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + user.token;
  } catch (e) {
    user = {uuid: '', token: ''};
  }
}
export default createStore({
  state: {
    status: '',
    user: user,
    userInfos: {},
  },
  mutations: {
    [...]
  },
  getters: {
  },
  actions: {
    [...]
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

I would like to be able to use api from my components. I have had several approaches:

1 - I have imported axios into my component, but this is not correct at all, as I will need axios in all my components.

2 - I've looked at different documentations that explain how to configure axios globally, but no two are the same and I couldn't get anything to work.

3 - I've tried calling api through strangenesses like this.$store.api in my methods, but obviously this is abused.

Can anyone help me understand what is the right way to use axios from my components and from the store with only one configuration? Knowing that I need to be able to keep my headers up to date for authentication with the Bearer Token (a mutation updates it in the store at user login).

```
main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faMedal } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faLaptopMedical } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faCookieBite } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faCoins } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faHourglassStart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faUpRightFromSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faInfo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faGears } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(
    faMedal,
    faCoins,
    faLaptopMedical,
    faCookieBite,
    faHourglassStart,
    faUpRightFromSquare,
    faInfo,
    faGears
);

createApp(App)
    .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app')
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello, have you read documentation on Vuex ? You can write methods that do several stuff, including calling api endpoints using your axios instance in your store. Then, you can call these methods in any of your components

Comment: If you're creating a new app, I would use Pinia, which is really the next version of VueX. Don't put the user in localStorage, but in a store that you can access from all views and components.

Comment: @aymcg31 - The store is for storing a state of my information. But I want to call an endpoint that I don't want to store, so locally in my component. And in the documentation, I didn't read anything that explains me how to configure axios once to use it in my components and in my store. I only have an explanation of what the store contains and how to use http requests through Axios. But those two things I understood and it doesn't answer my purpose :/ Or maybe I really didn't understand anything I read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way, but by doing so, it allows me to use the store api in my components.

```
store/index.js

state: {
    api: {},
    [...]
},
mutations: {
    setApi: function (state, api) {
      state.api = api;
    },
    connexionUser: function (state, user) {
      state.user = user;
      api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + user.token;
      state.api = api;
    },
    [...]
},
actions: {
     setApi: ({commit}) => {
      commit('setApi', api);
    },
    [...]
},
```

```
App.vue

mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setApi');
    [...]
  }
```

Like this, offline, it loads api which is set at the top of my store (see in my question) and when I log in, I update api in state to have JWT authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a new app, I would use Pinia, which is really the next version of VueX. Don't put the user in localStorage, but in a store that you can access from all views and components.

So Axios setup in `composables/myaxiosfile.js`

```js
// src/stores/oneStore.js

import { defineStore } from "pinia";

// Possibly import and deconstruct functions from @/api.js and use
// those functions in the "actions" section of the store, 
// updating the state according to the answer of the api call.

export const useOneStore = defineStore("oneStore", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      user: true
    }
  }
  // actions
  // getters
})
```

and in a component :

```
import { useOneStore } from '../stores/oneStore';
const oneStore = useOneStore()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to understand the basics first before I start looking at alternatives. :) I'll make a note of it in my upcoming discovery todolist.